# how far can i span with a double 2x12 beam with plywood in-between, glued and screwed

Tags: wood

I'm building a carport and I need to span 15 1/2 feet, the roof will be trusses 24 feet long 4/12 pitch on 24  inch centers with metal roof. will a double 2x12 beam with plywood in-between glued and screwed support the roof without sagging?

Comment: Where do you live? Important so snow loads can be determined

Comment: all beams sag a bit.   what grade of 2x12?  why add plywood? where do you get 15 foot long plywood?

Comment: @Jasen, I'm assuming the plywood in between is a 1/2" thickness to make the beam an even 4" wide. OP: is that the case?

Comment: Do you really need to double 2x12’s here? My barn has side area covers that are 14’ clear with metal roofing on 16” centers we do have occasional snow issues but I think mine are only 2x10, I will double check tonight. @jason rim Joist comes in longer lengths but that would not be needed here.